# Surface Pro 3 touch and home button drivers breaking after sysprep and capture?

Tags: windows-8, drivers

hoping someone might be able to help me here.

I'm running deployments for Surface Pro 3s in our environment and we have a working deployment system with WDS/MDT 2012 on a Server 2012 box, and things have been working fine up until now.

We have a WIM that we've been using to deploy Windows 8.1 to our Surfaces, but I wanted to edit the WIM, so I deployed it to a Surface Pro 3, made the changes we needed, and ran a sysprep and capture Task Sequence.  After the capture completed (it completed fine) I wiped the SP3 and tested deploying the newly captured WIM to make sure the changes had stuck, and now the touch driver and the home button don't work.

Device manager shows the Home Button as a bad driver, and deleting it seems to fix the problem, but I don't understand what would've changed between it working, capturing, and redploying.  Same thing for the touch drivers.

Has anybody seen anything like this?  If you have questions, feel free to let me know and I'll provide as much detail as I can.

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)